# Zeppelin 0.7.2 org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException with Spark and HighCharts

Tags: apache-zeppelin

If I add this artifact to Zeppelin  com.knockdata:spark-highcharts:0.6.4 it gives the error org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

Even a simple example like this causes the error:

```
val x = Array(1,2,3,4)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(x)
```

The problem is definitely related to %spark as %md and %sh work.  I have Spark version spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6.

There are no messages in the Spark logs.  In zeppelin-interpreter-spark-root-(hostname).log it says:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
 BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:757)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:706)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.convert(RemoteInterprete
rServer.java:425)
```

org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.wrapRefArray([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray;

Comment: check the tmp files for spark and make sure there is space available

Comment: I updated Spark to spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 and that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

`spark-highcharts:0.6.4` does not support `zeppelin:0.7.2`. There is a dependency from `spark-highcharts` which clearly state which `zeppelin` version to use and it is not binary compatible. That is why the error reported.

The version has been bumped to `spark-highcharts:0.6.5` to support `zeppelin:0.7.2(spark:2.1)`.

Comment: Changed to new artificate now says java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapper cannot be cast to scala.collection.MapLike
 at scala.sys.package$.env(package.scala:61)

Comment: Zeppelin-0.7.2 support up to spark-2.1. spark-highcharts:0.6.5 build with zeppelin:0.7.2 with spark:2.1. you can modify the version in pom file and recompile it if you wanna use spark:2.2.